# Resolving ANDROIDAPI and FMX units

Tags: android, delphi

I'm totally new in Delphi Android programming and I need to create a very simple Android App that should send a simple SMS message.

I found [an example](http://delphi-android.blogspot.rs/2013/10/how-to-send-sms-with-delphi-on-android.html) on the internet and it looks quite simple...

```
uses
  FMX.Helpers.Android,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.JNI.Telephony;

procedure SendSMS (target,messagestr:string);
var
  smsManager: JSmsManager;
  smsTo: JString;
begin
  smsManager:= TJSmsManager.JavaClass.getDefault;
  smsTo:= StringToJString(target);
  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsTo, nil, StringToJString(messagestr), nil, nil);
end;
```

But...

When I try to put those lines in USES clause, I get them red-underlined followed by the message "*Cannot resolve unit name...*". I found all those units (.DCU, .O and .PAS) in folders on my computer and added those paths in *Search Path* and *Browsing Path* in *Tools/Library/Android*...

I have the latest JDK, Android SDK and Android NDK...

I use Delphi XE8, but I get the exactly same message in Delphi 10...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did the red underline disappear after an attempt to compile or build? If yes, it is only the design time parser being 'lazy'. You better revert the changes you did to the path settings.

Comment: I tried that, but compiler raises an exception... This is usual "problem" and I'm familiar with it from standard Delphi applications... :(

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure to start a Delphi multi-device application in D10 and switch the target platform to 'Android'. Then hook up your emulator or device. The FMX - and the AndroidApi units are not in scope on a Win32/Win64 project.

Comment: Of course... Thats how I started writing my first Delphi Android application... and then the problem occurs... :)

Comment: Do it again. Check your work. In my own Android project, if I switch the target platform to Win32, by double-click on the target "32-bit Windows" then the AndroidApi. units get red wiggles. If I switch back to 'Android - Android SDK 24.3.3 32 bit', the red wiggles go away. It is possible that your SDK isn't properly installed. See the Embarcadeo website to get help to do it properly. It is a difficult job to install it if it is not correctly installed.